Show count on Google cloud Metrics explorer
Is it possible to show number of API request in the Google cloud metrics explorer?
I can see the request on dashboard but there is a delay in updating the table and in metrics explorer the time filter is helpful.
The value is now set to requests/sec but I would like to know the count within selected timeframe.
Thanks in advance
[screenshots of filter settings
Tried changing the y-axis assignment. Different filter options.

MQL is no longer recommended (aka being deprecated). You are encouraged to learn PromQL. You can use PromQL increase to measure the increase over the metrics explorer time range and show the results using TABLE. The metric will be serviceruntime_googleapis_com:api_request_count{monitored_resource="consumed_api"} but you'll need to add your service filter using a RegEx service="(directions|geolocation).googleapis.com"

sum by(service) (increase(serviceruntime_googleapis_com:api_request_count{monitored_resource="consumed_api",service=~"(directions|geolocation).googleapis.com"}[${__interval}]))
